# Unwanted Crossfade Effect in SwiftUI's Matched Geometry Effect

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation, swiftui-matchedgeometryeffect

In SwiftUI, I'm working with two screens, Screen A and Screen B. I'm attempting to create a transition effect using SwiftUI's matched geometry feature. The transition involves two rounded rectangles: one on Screen A, which appears as a circle due to its corner radius and size, and another on Screen B with a zero corner radius, serving as the background.

Expected Behavior:

I anticipated the animation would display as a seamless morphing of a single object from one configuration to another, specifically altering the corner radius, height, and width.

Actual Behavior:

However, while at first glance that is what appears to happen, if you look closer, you see the transition seems to be more of a crossfade. As it fades out, the source shape *does* interpolate its corner radius towards the target configuration, but the target shape, as it fades in does not interpolate *from* the source radius.

This screenshot of the top right section of the animation at approx 50% elapsed illustrates the undesired behavior:

[image]

Its seems unlikely the cross fade can simply be "turned off" ... I suppose a cross fade may be essential to matchedGeometry effect, as it seems it would be the only way to interpolate between certain properties like a different fill... *but even if this is true, it wouldn't be apparent if only the target shape was also interpolating its shape... which it is not in this case.*

I would like any answer *not* to change the animation mechanism -- this is just a simplified version of a larger project.  The animation must be triggered by withAnimation{} and act upon the navController.screen.

Minimal Example Code:

Main Screen:

```
enum Screen {
    case main, target
}

@Observable
class Nav {
    var screen:Screen = .main
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(Nav.self) var navController
    
    // matched geometry
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        
        switch navController.screen {
        case .main:
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "circleToBackground", in: namespace)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 4.0)){
                            navController.screen = .target
                        }
                    }
            }
            
        case .target:
            TargetScreen(namespace: namespace)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Target Screen:

```
struct TargetScreen: View {
    
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    @Environment(Nav.self) var navController
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [Color.green, Color.white], startPoint: UnitPoint(x:0.5,y:0.0), endPoint: UnitPoint(x:0.5,y:1.0)))
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "circleToBackground", in: namespace)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            Text("BACK").onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    navController.screen = .main
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your code worked for me.  How did you add the `Nav` instance to the environment?  Just with ` ContentView().environment(Nav())`?

Comment: Yea that way. it doesnt crash and it “works” for me too… just the behavior is undesired and understood by me.  I need to edit/clarify the question with an image.

Comment: The behaviour I see is the behaviour that you say you want.  The "Back" text fades but the circle morphs into the rectangle and vice-versa

Comment: Looking more closely I can see what you are describing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70305354/how-can-i-remove-control-fade-effect-from-matchedgeometryeffect

Comment: Thank you.  Since that question is using a different setup and mechanism for the animation, I'm not sure how to apply the solution from it.

Comment: I tried it on your code, using a `.scale` transition, gets rid of the opacity fade, but isn't perfect.

Comment: This post might help: [How can I transition from a circle/rounded rectangle to a rectangle in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76937415/20386264)